# Is it possible to pass 3 strings to 1 javascript function?

Tags: javascript

How do i pass 3 strings, 2 text from input fields, and 1 integer value to the same function so that i can then generate a xmlhttp.open request to a live database search script?

so that it generates something along the lines of....

XML..

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","search.php?brand="+brand+"&item="+item+"&id="+IdtoEdit,true);  
mlhttp.send();
```

**update**

JS

```
function showResult(str,IdtoEdit) {
    if (str.length==0) {
        document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML="";
        document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="0px";
        return;
    }

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {  // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="1px solid #A5ACB2";
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","search.php?q="+str+"&id="+IdtoEdit,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

i want 2 fields to be able to pass to this 1 function...

inputs...

```
<input type="text" id="brandsearch" value="" onkeyup="showResult(this.value,currCount); showsearch('livesearch');" autocomplete="off" onKeyPress="return disableEnterKey(event)" />
<input type="text" id="itemsearch" value="" onkeyup="showResult(this.value,currCount); showsearch('livesearch');" autocomplete="off" onKeyPress="return disableEnterKey(event)" />
```

Comment: How do you pass in one?

Comment: How are you currently doing it?

Comment: with a single input which gives me brand, but i need to also add another...let me update...

Comment: So, you want them both to be able to call the same function, and, in each case, pass the text from both fields?

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new function with tree parameters. Javascript is dynamically typed so you do not have to specify what type those parameters have. Even if the last parameter is an integer, Javascript will automatically convert that integer to a string when you concatinate it to a existing string.

```js
function myfunc(brand, item, idtoEdit) {
  xmlhttp.open("GET","search.php?brand="+brand+"&item="+item+"&id="+IdtoEdit,true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So make a single function that all the elements trigger. Have it look up the values and make the Ajax call.

```
function makeCall() {
   var val1 = document.getElementById("tb1").value;
   var val2 = document.getElementById("tb2").value;
   var val3 = document.getElementById("tb3").value;
   console.log(val1, val2, val3);
}
```

And making Ajax calls on keyup is going to get messy with a fast typer! You need to throttle/debounce the calls!

Answer (score 0):

you'll want something along the line of:

```
function showResult(IdtoEdit) {
var brand = document.getElementById("brandsearch").value
var item = document.getElementById("itemsearch").value
if ((brand.length==0)&&(item.length==0)) {
    document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML="";
    document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="0px";
    return;
}

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else {  // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
        document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="1px solid #A5ACB2";
    }
}

xmlhttp.open("GET","search.php?brand="+brand+"item="+item+"&id="+IdtoEdit,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

}

and for your input fields:

```
<input type="text" id="brandsearch" value="" onkeyup="showResult(currCount); showsearch('livesearch');" autocomplete="off" onKeyPress="return disableEnterKey(event)" />

<input type="text" id="itemsearch" value="" onkeyup="showResult(currCount); showsearch('livesearch');" autocomplete="off" onKeyPress="return disableEnterKey(event)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is a really big need for this function to be flexible (i.e., there are other fields that will also call this function), I would simply get the values from within the function itself:

```
function showResult(IdtoEdit) {
    var sBrandVal = document.getElementById("brandsearch").value;
    var sItemVal = document.getElementById("itemsearch").value;

    . . .

    xmlhttp.open("GET","search.php?brand=" + sBrandVal  + "&item=" + sItemVal + "&id=" + IdtoEdit, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Then, you would just call the function with: `showResult(currCount);`

---

If you DO need that flexibility, you would add a second parameter to the function, like this:

```
function showResult(str1, str2, IdtoEdit) {

    . . .

    xmlhttp.open("GET","search.php?q1=" + str1 + "&q2=" + str2 + "&id=" + IdtoEdit, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Then, when you called it, you would change the `showResult()` call to pass in the values from both of the fields . . . `showResult(this.value, currCount);` would become these (for the two different fields):

```
 showResult(this.value, document.getElementById("itemsearch").value, currCount);
```

. . . and . . .

```
 showResult(document.getElementById("brandsearch").value, this.value, currCount);
```